# How to generate Windows OpenSSH default config file?

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I'd like to know where is the default OpenSSH config file ("sshd_config" for Linux) or if not exists how to generate the file.

I thought SSH setting file "sshd_config" and "config" is the same format and same files, but apparently they are not. Because I copy and pasted `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd_config_default` to `C:/Users/user/.ssh/config` and I didn't work, and I got an error it says the format is invalid:

```
PS C:\Users\tmp> ssh user@192.168.0.123
C:\\Users\\tmp/.ssh/config: line 38: Bad configuration option: authorizedkeysfile
C:\\Users\\tmp/.ssh/config: line 76: Bad configuration option: subsystem
Unsupported Match attribute Group
C:\\Users\\tmp/.ssh/config line 84: Bad Match condition
```

So, I'd like to know what the Windows OpenSSH default config file looks like. Without knowing it, I have no idea and cannot change lines to change the SSH setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH issue 1297](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1297), you should simply modify `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd_config_default` and then restart the SSH service.

No need to copy it/rename it elsewhere (except, may be, to keep the original version)

The `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file is used only on the client side, not by the SSH server/service.

As noted in "[Unable to get public-key login to work on Windows 10 ssh server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58651797/6309)", the `sshd_config` can be added in:

```
C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config
```

Comment: It didn't solve the issue. I tried to edit sshd_config_default but I got an error and couldn't save the file. I googled and found people saying it's not C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd_config_default but C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config the configuration file is.

Comment: Ok. I suppose it would have to be modified through an administrator session (CMD opened as administrator)

Comment: @pupsozeyde I have found the path of the config file, but I see you already mentioned it in your next question.